# Can I bring food which is not recognised as safe through US customs?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

On my trip to the US, I'm planning to bring condiments containing [pink pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_peppercorn), typical of French cuisine, as a gift. Something like this:

[image]

As I understand, there should be no problem with bringing commercially packaged foods. However, since pink peppercorn lacks GRAS (generally recognized as safe) status in the US, I wonder if there are additional restrictions I could face.

Also, should I declare it or just pack in my luggage and go ahead?

Comment: Always declare your food, even food that is allowed. Not doing so is a great way to have a _really bad day_ at Customs.

Comment: And you should be okay with the product pictured, as [CBP info on such Food Products (Prepared)](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/know-before-you-go/prohibited-and-restricted-items) says _As a general rule, condiments, vinegars, oils, packaged spices, honey, coffee and tea are admissible._

Comment: GRAS status appears to be for food *additives,* not for foods themselves. Also, many customs regulations have nothing to do with safety.

Comment: @phoog I don't quite understand the difference. Say, I'm a company who wants to sell pink pepper in the US, will in be easier to do so if I sell chicken wings with pink pepper than if I were to sell pink pepper alone? Or did you mean something else entirely?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the point is that *pepper* isn't something you would find in the database.  It's a database of chemicals, or more precisely, of *substances,* (derived from foods) rather than of foods themselves.  For example, there is a (closed) entry for *Piperine derived from the fruits of Piper nigrum L (black pepper) or P. longum (long pepper).*  Anyway, the premise of your question is incorrect, as *Schinus molle* **is** recognized as safe by regulation: http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e956d645a8b4e6b3e34e4e5d1b690209&mc=true&node=pt21.3.182&rgn=div5#se21.3.182_110

Comment: Try this search to see whether "chocolate" is GRAS, and you ought to see what I mean when I say the database is not intended to list consumer foods; it lists food additives: http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/fdcc/?set=GRASNotices&sort=GRN_No&order=DESC&startrow=1&type=basic&search=chocolate

Comment: Anyway, the main reason things are prohibited is not because of the danger they pose to *people,* but because of the danger they pose to *agriculture* (that is, other plants and animals).  See https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/agricultural-items.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can with some kinds of food. I routinely bring in Kinder Surprise eggs which are apparently banned by FDA. As long as you a) declare everything to US Customs, and b) the amount you're bringing is obviously for personal consumption, you are solid. While Customs can in theory confiscate this stuff, in my experience they always showed leeway as long as two conditions above were satisfied.

However if you're bringing meat, raw fruit/veggies or dairy, those might not be allowed - and I've seen those confiscated at secondary control.